# Remove some numbers with dots from output with sed

Tags: sed

I have this output:

```
1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0
```

How can i sed it to only print

```
1024x768
```

?

By the way, anyone can give some documentations for the Sed? I need to learn how to use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Strip Everything Starting with Whitespace

Use a POSIX character class to strip everything after the whitespace with sed. For example:

```
$ echo '1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0' | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+.*//'
1024x768
```

### Use Awk Instead

While you could use sed, the problem is much nicer to solve in awk because of its native field-splitting. For example:

```
$ echo '1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0' | awk '{print $1}'
1024x768
```

Comment: That was my first thought but OP did ask for `sed`... I was quite conflicted to give what I considered the "wrong" answer, so thanks for providing the alternative.

Comment: After your edit your answer deserves the upvote. But why is there a backslash before the `+` sign?

Comment: @Floris With some seds, unless you use `--regexp-extended` you'll need to escape the `+` to use it as a matching expression rather than a literal character.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I guess I am spoilt with the version I use... Need to become aware of "how the other side seds".

Comment: The `+` sign is useless, as followed by `.*` there is no matter if there is another space or not. So `s/[[:space:]].*$//` would suffer (or `s/\s.*$//` ;-) .

Answer (score 0):

You could process your line with

```
sed 's/\s.*$//'
```

"Find everything after the first white space and replace with nothing"

As was pointed out in the comments,, the `\s` shorthand doesn't work in all versions of `sed`, and the $ sign is superfluous; you could use `sed 's/[\t ].*//` to be more generally applicable. "Find everything after the first tab or space, and remove it".

Of course I am guessing a little bit about the "general case" of the string you want to strip... Your question seemed to imply you wanted to remove all numbers with dots in them, which would be a different expression, like this:

```
sed 's/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+//g'
```

"Replace a block of test that starts with any combination of the numbers zero through nine, followed by a dot, followed by another group of at least one digit, with nothing"

For good sed documentation see http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

`awk` is probably the better tool in this instance though ( see codegnome's answer)

Comment: You don't need to anchor the expression with the dollar sign since `.*` is greedy. Also, not all versions of sed support the PCRE-compatible `\s` notation.

Answer (score 0):

when I need to extract strings from text, `grep` comes up first:

```
grep -o '^[^ ]*'
```

with your data:

```
kent$  echo "1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0"|grep -o '^[^ ]*'
1024x768
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\s*([0-9]+)?\.[0-9]+\s*//g;/./!d' file
```

This deletes any decimal numbers and surrounding white space. If nothing remains in the line it deletes the empty line as well.

See [here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/) for a wealth of sed material.